# Is there a way to use a Case statement to read from one field and change another field?

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a simple MS SQL database created from an import from a CSV file. I need to check a field to see if a word is in that field, and if it is, change the contents of another field. Like this:

When [Category] contains the word 'Server' change [Form_Factor] to 'Server'.

I'm not a MS SQL person, and I have stumped my Database administrator for some reason.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd even need a case statement for this. Assuming your table is called myTable in the dbo schema (you didn't specify, but it isn't particularly important) and we're talking about updating the field in the same row.

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET Form_Factor = 'Server'
WHERE Category LIKE '%Server%'
```

Msdn link: [Update with Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-the-where-clause)

I don't see how any database professional can be stumped by this though.. unless the problem is much more complex than you are letting on.

Answer (score 0):

I used the

```
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET Form_Factor = 'Server'
    WHERE Category LIKE '%Server%'
```

before my `SELECT` statement. I wasn't sure the application I was using would allow that, but it did and now I'm very happy.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Hi Erick, did you lose access to the account you originally posted the question on?

Comment: @jcolebrand this is copy and paste from an earlier answer.  The OP should accept that answer and this one should be deleted.

Comment: @JamesJenkins the users are the same, it would seem. Hence my asking if they lost access to their original account so I can give guidance on how to merge them.

Comment: @jcolebrand I get that the OP and this answer are posted by the same person with similar accounts. But this answer was originally posted by a different user https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/256863/21924 The OP is reflecting the answer that solved their problem.

Comment: I submitted the question as anonymous, and then created an account. EHacking and Erick.Hacking@Navistar.com are the same if they can be merged.

Comment: @EHacking you'll want to merge your two accounts and then you'll want to award a checkmark to the answer that solved it for you. When you do that, ping me here and I can drop this answer from the system. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @JamesJenkins right and it would be silly to rush deleting this answer before he can claim the account to apply the checkmark. I appreciate your helpfulness.